# iOS9 - Universal Links - How to implement on internal web server

Tags: ios9, ios-universal-links

we are currently stuck with this feature so I want to give it a shot by asking here ..

We want to implement universal links. User receives sms with http link and the url should be passed to the app if installed - if not to safari where there is a download link to the store .. so far so easy.

I used basically the tutorial from ray wenderlich and the apple docs but its not working because .. I guess the web server where the file "apple-app-site-association" is stored needs to reachable from external - right? Atm we are developing completely internal so the web server is currently not reachable.

Could this be the problem? Didn't find precise information about that in the docs... its just saying "upload it to your web server in the root dir .." but no more details.

Thanks in the advance for every help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `apple-app-site-association` file just needs to be reachable from the device, so whether that is internal or external doesn't make any difference. But it does need to be reachable via an appropriate HTTPS connection with a valid SSL certificate. That might be a pain to set up correctly on an internal network, and any sort of authentication would cause the request to fail.

It sounds like you're trying to implement something very similar to Branch's free [text me the app](https://dev.branch.io/features/text-me-the-app/overview/) service, which already supports Universal Links. You might look there if you don't feel like building the whole thing from scratch! *(full disclosure: I'm the Branch team)*